# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) why?

Tags: mysql, popsql

I am a beginner on sql. I am using Win 10. When I started to create a table on popsql online version, I got this error message:

Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

The connection looks like below: [connection window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzS9R.png)

I did not find any file ending with .sock on my computer. I google it and it says maybe whatever.sock is under another directory, or I missed my.cnf (did not know how to create one...) Can someone help me with that?

Comment: windowes has no sockets it has named pipes, and it is unclear what you try to connect where. sockets can also only be used in a local system aka localhost

Comment: heyy.. I was trying to connect to localhost. I was confused, because it was looking for sock, but none on my computer... how to fix that

Comment: fix what exactly, on windows are no sockets so you can't connect to them, and ypour image shows also no option- locahost will in wondows first try named pipes and then tcpip